# SLIP Connections in Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, serial

I'm looking for a way to set up a SLIP connection in Windows 7. I found [these instructions](http://www.sics.se/~bg/telos/slipintro.pdf) for setting it up under Windows XP, but I can't seem to figure out if it's possible under 7.

[More info on SLIP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SLIP) if you're unfamiliar with it.

Thanks for your help.

EDIT: I'm using SLIP for a two-way radio link with some custom hardware, where PPP is just overkill. Thanks for your help.

Comment: I'm just curious: What does SLIP get used for these days? Just legacy systems, or are there "modern" needs for it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A couple of thoughts:

- You would probably want CSLIP rather than SLIP (7 byte overhead vs 40)
- You probably want PPP anyway since PPP does compression of the message body, unless either your packets will be very small or you know that the packet radio system is doing compression of its own. Error detection may also be a factor (SLIP lacks it)
- What are you going to be connecting to? Don't forget that both ends will need to support your protocol.

Answer (score 0):

I'd say your out of luck. 
 Best bet is to run XP in a virtual machine on windows 7 & get it running that way.
I too am curious, what are you using SLIP for? & why can't you use PPP?

Comment: SLIP has little overhead in comparison to PPP, though not *that* much overhead.  If working packet radio however you want to be old-school and save as much as possible.

I always liked SLIP, it just *seemed* faster than PPP working telnet at 9600 baud.